# Bibliography from JABREF adds hypelink i. How can I remove this

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, jabref

I have used Jabref to create my `.bib` file. If I place the `.bib` in my latex document, the letter i pops up after every reference. The letter i is actually a hyperlink, referring to the place I have placed `\cite{}`.

Example:
[7] G.Rizzoni, L. Guzzella, and B. M. Baumann. "Unied Modeling of Hybrid Electric Vehicle
Drivetrains". IEEE/ASME Trans on Mechatronics, vol. 58(no. 3):pp. 246{257, Sep. 1999. i

Unfortunately the last i is shown on printed versions of the pdf aswel. Does anyone have any thoughts on how to remove this letter/hyperlink?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The process for including `.bib` files entails the use of a specific compilation sequence: `pdflatex`, `bibtex` (or `biber`, if you use [`biblatex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex)), `pdflatex`, `pdflatex`. Are you doing this?

Comment: I bet your document has only a single page and this has nothing to do with jabref. Try to load bibtex using `\usepackage[backref=false]{biblatex}`.

Comment: If you do not use `biblatex`, you should load `hyperref` without option `backref` or with option `backref=false`.